# Rainfall data, can't get value of table?

Tags: r, format

I tried to analyse rainfall data. But my problem is that I have data in format:

```
head(dati)
    X    X.1 X.2   X.3     1. stat   2. stat 3.stat 4. stat  5. stat
2 2013   1 Val01 00:00           0     0.7                      0.2
3 2013   1 Val01 01:00           0     0.5                      0.2
4 2013   1 Val01 02:00           0       0                      0.2
5 2013   1 Val01 03:00           0       0                        0
6 2013   1 Val01 04:00           0       0                      0.1
7 2013   1 Val01 05:00           0       0                        0
```

As you see there are some spaces in columns, and when I try to get `dati[1,5]` I get

```
[1] 0.7

53 Levels:  0 0.1 0.2  0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1 1.1 1.2 1.3 ... HPRAB
```

I understand that I need get only one number: 0.7. How can I do that and why there are information about levels?

My code was:

```
dati<-read.csv2("precipitation.csv", header = TRUE,row.names=NULL,
     sep = ";", quote = "", dec = "," , fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")
attach(dati)

 dati[1,1]
[1] 2013
> dati[1,6]
[1] 0.7
53 Levels:  0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 ... HPRAB
> dati[1,3]
[1] Val01
32 Levels:  Val01 Val02 Val03 Val04 Val05 Val06 Val07 Val08 Val09 Val10 Val11 Val12 ... Val31
> dati[1,4]
[1] 00:00
25 Levels:  00:00 01:00 02:00 03:00 04:00 05:00 06:00 07:00 08:00 09:00 10:00 11:00 ... 23:00
>
```

Resolved! Next code works correctly!

```
dati<-read.csv2("precipitation.csv", header = TRUE,row.names=NULL,
         sep = ";", quote = "", dec = "," , fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")
    attach(dati)
as.numeric(as.character(dati[1,i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get information about levels because those columns are stored as `factor`s (see `?factor`). You can use `as.numeric(as.character(df$yourcolumn))` to convert a factor to numeric (where `df` is your data.frame and `yourcolumn` the column you want to convert).

Check to see if you have any characters (other than NA) in those columns, because R would normally interpret data with only numbers (and NA) as numeric.